# Android : Least recently used (LRU) algorithm implementation in java?

Tags: java, android, lru

In my application am having lot bitmaps around 1000. I have to  merge them as a single image. In order to do this , loading currently needed bitmaps from sdcard .In this process i have to recyle Least recently used bitmaps other wise dvm throws out of memory error  . so can any one tell me how to accomplish this task (Least recently used ) in java.??

Thank you,
Srinivas

Comment: if you google for "lru cache java" you'll find many tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into the [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) or LinkedHashSet implementations in the Collections API, which provide support for a highly-configurable LRU framework.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedHashMap would be perfect fit for this type of problems.removeEldestEntry() method of LinkedHashMap class returns true to remove oldest entry